# How to derive the approximation $\tan(x)\simeq \frac{x}{1-x^2/3}$

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

I was wondering how one could derive the

$$\tan(x)\simeq \frac{x}{1-x^2/3}$$

valid for small $x$ values.

This is similar to the ratio of the small $x$ expansions of $\sin(x)$  an $\cos(x)$, however that would yield

$$\tan(x)\simeq \frac{x}{1-x^2/2}$$

so I have been left slightly confused. Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: In my notes this seems to be some sort of recursive fraction approximation. A second version I have written is:

$$
\tan(x)\simeq 
%%%
\frac{\lambda}
{1-\frac{\lambda^2}{3-\frac{\lambda^2}{5-\lambda^2/2}}}
$$

EDIT: Thanks for your great answers! You can also find this derived in the references to Equation 33 here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html

Wall, H. S. (1948). Analytic theory of continued fractions. pg. 349

C.D., O. (1963). Continued fractions. pg. 138

Comment: If you use the Taylor expansion of sin(x) and cos(x) I believe you would get the one you suggested too.

Comment: @HenryLee: Yes, it's quite frustrating to see where this other one came from.

Comment: Somehow, $3$ gives a smaller error, even though the Taylor expansions would suggest $2$. https://i.imgur.com/tczqY6G.png

Comment: Yes, I think that's why I used it. I'm digging through thesis notes currently trying to write up. Past me apparently didn't think it was useful to write where this came from.

Comment: what is this for?

Comment: @Freeman Perhaps you could show with Pade Approximants what the best coefficients are. This might explain why $1/3$ is a more accurate approximation than $1/2$.

Comment: @HenryLee It's to be used to approximate the smallest solution to a dispersion relation.

Comment: @Jam hmm, I haven't encountered that before, I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This relation con be derived using a [Pade approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). Define a function

$$
R(x) = \frac{a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_m x^m}{1 + b_1 x + \cdots + b_n x^n}
$$

That agrees with $f$ up to some order

$$
\left.\frac{{\rm d}^kf}{{\rm d}x^k}\right|_{x=0}
 = 
\left.\frac{{\rm d}^kR}{{\rm d}x^k}\right|_{x=0} ~~~\mbox{for}~~ k = 0, 1, \cdots
$$

So in your example, take $m=1$ and $n=2$ and $f(x) = \tan(x)$, this would lead to the equations

\begin{eqnarray}
a_0 &=&0 \\
a_1 - a_0 b_1 &=& 1 \\
-2a_1 b_1 + a_0(2b_1^2 - 2b_2) &=&0 \\
3a_1(2 b_1^2 - 2b_2) + a_0(-6b_1^3 + 12 b_1 b_2) &=& 2
\end{eqnarray}

whose solution is

$$
a_0 = 0, a_1 =1, b_1 = 0~~\mbox{and}~~ b_2=-1/3
$$

That is

$$
\tan(x) \approx \frac{x}{1 - x^2/3}
$$

which aggress up to the fourth derivative!

Comment: Ah awesome! That's really helpful of you, and I learnt something new! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Freeman Happy to help

Comment: Today I learned! :)

Answer (score 2):

Recall that

$$\tan(x)= x+\frac13x^3+o(x^3)$$

and by binomial expansion as $x\to 0$

$$\frac{x}{1-x^2/3}=x(1-x^2/3)^{-1}\sim x+\frac13x^3$$

thus

$$\tan(x)\sim x+\frac13x^3\sim \frac{x}{1-x^2/3}$$

Note that from here

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

to obtain the same result we need to expand to the 3rd order that is

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{x-\frac16x^3+o(x^3)}{1-\frac12x^2+o(x^3)}=(x-\frac16x^3+o(x^3))(1-\frac12x^2+o(x^3))^{-1}=(x-\frac16x^3+o(x^3))(1+\frac12x^2+o(x^3))=x-\frac16x^3+\frac12x^3+o(x^3)=x+\frac13x^3+o(x^3)$$

Comment: That's pretty neat! Thank you! caverac also posted a nice proof about the same time as you, ideally I would like to accept both answers, but as caverac has less reputation than you I will accept theirs. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Freeman You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Freeman I add something for the derivation from $\sin x/\cos x$

Answer (score 1):

I think your derivation is correct. Please refer to [this former post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914886/quadratic-approximation-of-tanx-at-0) for more information! :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is very clear how to derive that one. See my edit, I think it's from a recursive fraction approximation.

Comment: I don't think this answer quite addresses the question, or where the $1/3$ term comes from.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative derivation, you may use [the Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) and compute the inverse function of an algebraic function. This gives
$$ \tan(x) \approx \frac{3x+2x\sqrt{9-3x^2}}{9-4x^2}\quad\text{for }x\approx0 $$
which is even more accurate than $\tan x\approx \frac{x}{1-x^2/3}$. As already shown, the last approximation can be derived from Padé approximants or generalized [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction).

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is an answer to the question or just a note that there are other possible approximations.

Comment: @Jam: This proves a sharper approximation, from which $\tan(x)\approx \frac{x}{1-x^2/3}$ can be easily derived in a algebraic fashion.

Comment: A better approximation could be $\tan(x)=\frac{ x-\frac{x^3}{15}}{1-\frac{2 x^2}{5} }$